# Finding elements inside every cluster in scikit DBSCAN?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, scikit-learn, dbscan

I am trying to explore Scikit DBSCAN. There is something that I want to know. How can I know the points in every cluster.

This code is an [example](http://jaquesgrobler.github.io/online-sklearn-build/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html) in the scipy website :

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


##############################################################################
# Generate sample data
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=750, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.4,
                            random_state=0)

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

##############################################################################
# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
core_samples = db.core_sample_indices_
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels))
print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"


         % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))
        ##############################################################################
    #Modification I am doing 
    print labels 
    print labels[0]

unique_labels = set(labels)

for k in unique_labels:
    class_members = [index[0] for index in np.argwhere(labels == k)]
    #cluster_core_samples = [index for index in core_samples if labels[index] == k]

    print class_members[0]

    for index in class_members:
        x = X[index]
    print x
```

It seems that I need to find an algorithm to reverse engineering

```
StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

The scipy implementation of DBSCAN is presented on [DBSCAN Code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py) - [DBSCAN Test Unit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/tests/test_dbscan.py)

I'd like to print the three clusters and points that belong to every cluster.

**UPDATE**

When I am trying to run inverse_transform() function, I get an error at line

File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 384, in inverse_transform

You can find the code here: 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py

```
        if self.with_std:
            X *= self.std_
        if self.with_mean:
            X += self.mean_
```

This is where I got the error. Any ideas to solve this problem  ?

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that I need to find an algorithm to reverse engineering
>
> StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

Data transformes in sklearn are "reversable" (if they are not lossy), you should store your scaler object.

```
s = StandardScaler()
X = s.fit_transform(X)
```

and then if you want to retrieve unscaled versions

```
X = s.inverse_transform(X)
```

### regarding comment

Standard Scaler transforms data both ways just fine.

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array( [[1.0,2.0],[0.0,-4.0]])
>>> s = StandardScaler()
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 0., -4.]])
>>> a=s.fit_transform(x)
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.]])
>>> s.inverse_transform(a)
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 0., -4.]])
>>>
```

Comment: I am getting this error message : 
File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 384, in inverse_transform  
X *= self.std_ 
AttributeError: 'StandardScaler' object has no attribute 'std_'

Comment: Did you run `X = s.fit_transform(X)` before? It has to be fitted before it can transform data back.

Comment: yes!I did. I re-installed the lib as well, but still facing the same problem

Comment: When I added  StandardScaler(with_std=False,with_mean=False).inverse_transform(x) . It worked out, should I add this as well StandardScaler(with_std=False,with_mean=False).fit_transform and how bad it is to make std and mean false